# Drawing a customized frame using tcolorbox or tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

I am trying to draw this (it should adapt to text width and height).

[image]

I would like to use either tcolorbox or tikz.
Sorry for not providing any MWE, I have no clue how to start.
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe a good start could be reading and studying the examples from both packages you cite, try to write some code and ask for something more punctual. In this way it doesn’t sound like “do this for me”

Comment: Thank you, I have already done that but I didn't find anything that allows me to do it. I searched on Google but I didn't find what I was looking for. All I can do it draw a rectangle with \fbox, however, I can't think of a way to add these small circles automatically to fit the box frame size. Also I don't want to be limited to my example if other methods are easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want something simple

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw=orange, line width=6pt, inner sep=0.5cm, postaction={draw=yellow, line width=3pt, line cap=round, dash pattern=on 0pt off 5\pgflinewidth}] {$f(x)=\ldots$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Formula with orange frame and yellow dots]

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you @hpekristiansen

Answer (score 5):

I think use `tcolorbox` could be better. However you can write the your own frame code using `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{254,225,162}
\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{255,189,0}
\definecolor{myiframe}{RGB}{188,104,58}
\definecolor{mydframe}{RGB}{233,141,59}
\definecolor{mylframe}{RGB}{255,161,79}
\tikzfading[name=olight fade, inner color=transparent!0, outer color=transparent!100]
\tikzfading[name=light fade, inner color=transparent!0, outer color=transparent!95]
\tikzfading[name=ilight fade, inner color=transparent!0, outer color=transparent!100]
\newcommand{\addframe}[1]{{\noindent\tikz{
\node[inner sep=10pt,line width=0pt](current content){
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-1cm-20pt}
#1
\end{minipage}};
\draw [myiframe,line width=4pt] (current content.south west) rectangle (current content.north east);
\fill [mydframe] (current content.south west) -- ++(-0.5,-0.5) -- ([xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-0.5cm]current content.south east) -- (current content.south east) -- cycle;
\fill [mydframe] (current content.north east) -- ++(0.5,0.5) -- ([xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=0.5cm]current content.north west) -- (current content.north west) -- cycle;
\fill [mylframe] (current content.south west) -- ++(-0.5,-0.5) -- ([xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=0.5cm]current content.north west) -- (current content.north west) -- cycle;
\fill [mylframe] (current content.north east) -- ++(0.5,0.5) -- ([xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-0.5cm]current content.south east) -- (current content.south east) -- cycle;
\begin{scope}[remember picture,overlay]
\foreach \loc/\xshift/\yshift in {
north east/-1cm/0.25cm,
north/0cm/0.25cm,
north west/1cm/0.25cm,
west/-0.25cm/0cm,
south west/1cm/-0.25cm,
south/0cm/-0.25cm,
south east/-1cm/-0.25cm,
east/0.25cm/0cm}{
    \fill [myyellow,path fading=olight fade] ([xshift=\xshift,yshift=\yshift]current content.\loc) circle (0.5cm);
    \fill [myorange,path fading=light fade] ([xshift=\xshift,yshift=\yshift]current content.\loc) circle (0.4cm);
    \fill [myyellow,path fading=ilight fade] ([xshift=\xshift,yshift=\yshift]current content.\loc) ellipse [x radius=0.3cm, y radius=0.2cm];}
\end{scope}
}\par}}

\begin{document}
\addframe{
\begin{equation}
    E=m\cdot c^2
\end{equation}
}
\lipsum[1]
\addframe{\lipsum[1]}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \addframe{\caption{Table Caption}\label{tab:label}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        1 & 2 & 3  \\
        4 & 5 & 5  \\
        7 & 8 & 9
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very impressive!+1 for you. Nice and pro result!.

Comment: @Raffaele You could implement this code into `tcolorbox` customized box frame code.

Comment: No thanks, I dont know from where to start...Buona notte!

Comment: That's impressive. I'm going to use it for sure!

Answer (score 1):

Just to start,try this code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \filldraw[fill=gray!20,draw=blue,line width=20pt] (0,0) rectangle (7,5);
        \foreach \i in {1,...,6}{%
            \filldraw[yellow,line width=2pt] (\i,5) circle(5pt);
            \filldraw[yellow,line width=2pt] (\i,0) circle(5pt);
        }
        \foreach \i in {0,...,5}{%
        \filldraw[yellow,line width=2pt] (0,\i) circle(5pt);
        \filldraw[yellow,line width=2pt] (7,\i) circle(5pt);
        }
        \node[cyan] at (3.5,2.5)(a) {\LARGE $f(x)=\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x+2}}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Rafaele Santoro. This would have been perfect if the size was known beforehand. Is there a way to know the size of the formula, then to use this size to draw a rectangle?

Comment: @stargazer45 You need before to know the formula and then fix the dimensions 
of the rectangle.